# Access VBA merging Word template with query

Tags: ms-access, ms-word, vba

I want to create a template in Word, that I can then use Access to merge data into.  The Access data has various levels of grouping. Within each grouping, there are subqueries that may also have grouping. Because there is grouping, certain pages will need to be repeated.

Example: I have a query that prints the details of a classroom. There are many students in each classroom, as well. So, I would like to have a DOTM template that groups each student by class. Then prints the first class details, then the students, then moving on the next class, then students, etc.

The Access tables/queries, etc. are not an issue. It's creating a template, then merging it, that I'm having issues with. Right now, I just have a simple template (Dotm file). The file has some boilerplate stuff, and some bookmarks.  I then use this code to interact with the dotm file:

```
Dim objWord As Word.Application
Dim PauseTime, Start, Timer As Integer
Dim wrkCurrent As DAO.Workspace

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = False 'True is visible

Dim sql As String
sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_School"  'ex query that produces more that one record
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Set wrkCurrent = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(sql)

objWord.Documents.Add ("C:\test\Test.dotm")
'this template has one page, with one bookmark, School_Name.  What I want
' to happen is that, for every record, create a new page, with this 
'bookmark filled in.
If (Not rst.EOF) Then
    With rst
        Do Until .EOF
            objWord.ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("School_Name").Select
            objWord.Selection.Text = rst!school_name
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With
End If

objWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs ("C:\test\MyNewDocument.docx")
objWord.PrintOut
objWord.Quit
Set objWord = Nothing
```

The problem is that this only prints the first one, then errors. How would I do the grouping? FYI, I know I can do this in reports, but I must allow the report to be exported to Word, retaining images, graphics, etc. which the export loses.

Comment: You have several problems here.  The first issue, is that it would be best to use a mailMerge and not bookmarks.  The mailMerge would allow you to create a document with a different page for each record.  If you want to do bookmarks, then you have other problems.  When you replace a bookmark with text, the book mark is removed.  See here to keep the bookmark...http://word.mvps.org/faqs/macrosvba/InsertingTextAtBookmark.htm.  Aside from that, even if you properly replaced the bookmark, you are trying to replace the bookmark over and over again.  Nothing in your code adds a new page...

Comment: @OpiesDad Mmm, but mail merge isn't going to do the grouping / sub-queries. Makes no sense to suggest that for this task...

Comment: Yeah, that's my issue.  I need to allow for groupings.  Maybe Bookmarks aren't the best way to go about this, but I'm not sure merges are either.  I there were the ability to pull in a template, fill it in with data, and add it to a parent document, that might work.  But, im not sure that is possible.

Comment: @CindyMeister You're right, I should have thought about this more.  The bookmark problem I mentioned is accurate, however.

Comment: Jason, I concur with @OpiesDad analysis, with the exception of the mailmerge remark. Look into saving the element(s) that repeat(s) as a *BuildingBlock*. You store building blocks for such a purpose in the template, itself, inserting them as you need them. The BB can contain a/the bookmark. Since you don't need to re-use the bookmark once you've written to it, it's not a problem if your code deletes it when it writes. Then the bookmark will be there again each time you insert the BB.

Comment: hmm.  I've never heard of BuildingBlock's before.  I will look into it and see how it can help.

Comment: If anyone has any examples of this, that would be awesome!

Comment: I was able to add buildingBlocks, but I dont see a way to edit the bookmark withing a building block.  Anyone have an example?  I can post the code I have for the buildingblocks, if that would help

Comment: @jason The code would certainly help, but if you want anyone to see your comment, you need to use the "@" symbol followed by their name.  I just now saw your comment, although I have also never used BuildingBlocks and so cannot assist much there.